# How to speed up vagrant shared folder speed

Tags: windows, performance, vagrant

I've been using vagrant on windows 8 running a centos VM for about a week. Because I found that there are numerous issues with running things in the centos virtual environment when dealing with files in the shared folder (/vagrant), I've set up a file watcher that updates files automatically when I change them in windows and writes to somewhere under /home/vagrant/ . That way I have my project purely in a centos environment with none of the oddities that happen in the shared folder.

However, I've noticed that it takes about 15 seconds for files to sync. We're talking about files that are about 150 lines long or less - small files. 15 seconds is an eternity. So my questions are:

- What in god's name is going on?
- How can I speed this up at all? Less than a second would be ideal.

The edit/test cycle reminds me of compiling C code on Code Warrier. This is not what I want from a node.js workflow. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I would say nfs shared forlders... but not on windows, not supported by vagrant, sorry

Comment: The speed of the shared folder I've been using spontaneously sped up without me doing anything specific. Not sure why, but its not an issue for me anymore. I have no idea if it will spontaneously switch back to sucking tho...

Comment: The question is old, but I got here through google. Currently you can use NFS on windows. http://www.ravisagar.in/blog/how-speed-drupal-running-vagrant-windows-host

Answer (score 3):

The question is old, but I got here through google. Currently you can use NFS on Windows. http://ravisagar.in/blog/how-speed-drupal-running-vagrant-windows-host

This speeds things dramatically, about 10 times.

Comment: Ah interesting, Looks like this didn't exist when I asked the question: https://github.com/GM-Alex/vagrant-winnfsd . I'll have to try it out at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I would install a samba server on your vm and then mount the share in windows as a network drive. I have done this in the past and it means that things like saving are instant and you should not run into any of the issues that you would with the default vagrant share, just make sure that samba shares the files as the vagrant user.

I have not setup samba on centos before - I usually use ubuntu... but this seems like a fairly robust tutorial: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetUpSamba#head-1be77a3cb5ab61b8fd459182262e9a95db4b0aff

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when I have the problem again, I will certainly try this